# Material-UI: How to renderValue display label of select tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multiple-select

I'm using multiple select component of MUI, when user select it display the value of select tag to the user, but I want it display the label of select tag.

This is codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/embed/elated-bose-phh8xx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **trick** I have found is that you can called **find** method in **Chip Lable** and get that **object** by id then use its **label**

**Example Code:**

```
 <Chip key={value} label={DUMMY_DATA.find(item => item.id === value).label} variant="light" color="primary" size="small" />
```

[Read more about find Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)

**Complete code:**

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-chip-label">Chuyên mục</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-multiple-chip-label"
    id="demo-multiple-chip"
    multiple
    value={personName}
    onChange={handleChange}
    input={<OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Chuyên mục" />}
    renderValue={(selected) => (
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}>
        {selected.map((value) => (
          <Chip
            key={value}
            label={DUMMY_DATA.find((item) => item.id === value).label}
            variant="light"
            color="primary"
            size="small"
          />
        ))}
      </Box>
    )}
    MenuProps={MenuProps}
  >
    {DUMMY_DATA.map((o) => (
      <MenuItem key={o.id} value={o.id}>
        {o.label}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

Comment: This seems like a good way, I'll use it

Answer (score 1):

Write value={o.label} instead of value={o.id}

```
<MenuItem key={o.id} value={o.label}>
     {o.label}
 </MenuItem>
```

Hope it works fine.

Comment: I know this way, but this way will setState as label, not id. I want to display to the user side a label, but I want setState to be the id to insert into the database

Comment: Please add it to the question description.